# The Infinite Tetration of x?

Tags: tetration

The infinite tetration of ${x}$ basically means that we take a value and we continue to raise the value to its power forever. If that sounds confusing, it can be thought of as infinite repeated exponentiation of ${x}$. Now, my question is, will this value converge for any vale of ${x}$? In other words, is there a value that this will get infinitely close to when ${x}$ is a certain value?